# Dart The named parameter 'home' isn't defined

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

when I am trying to run an app in VS code, this message shows up "The named parameter 'home' isn't defined.".

It is a general problem for all flutter projects .flutter doctor says no issues.

I also tried creating a new project from scratch using android studio and Intellij and no progress .it says (theme: and home:) are not identified as named parameters.before that everything was perfectly fine ..please help! :(

Comment: maybe you modified the source code of:  MaterialApp

Comment: If true can i restore it back?

Comment: Do you have several versions of Flutter installed or something?

Comment: `git clean -xfd` in the Flutter install directory might restore your Flutter installation.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer running this command made all required annotations errors

Comment: Run `flutter doctor` that should fix it

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it seems like you may have modified your Flutter SDK (there was previously a bug in the analysis server that made this easy to do accidentally by running quick-fixes).

There's an open issue about having `flutter doctor` detect this here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25220

For now, running the git clean command Günter gave in the comments from inside your **Flutter SDK** folder should get things back to normal.